# How to show query results in Access sub-form from button

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have not done Microsoft Access forms for 15 years and now I have to amend a system using an Access front end (Microsoft Access 2016).  I am managing to resolve a lot of items quickly but one that I am struggling with is as follows.

One form that users input details of customer complaints - fields on this form include input of customer reference and defaults to first Customer in Customer list, selection of complaint type list box which also defaults to first in list and selection of financial year list box which defaults to current year.  Users want a button to show a list of previous customer complaints of this type in a financial year.  I can add the button later if I can just get the query and sub-form working

I have created the Access query which uses the relevant form fields (example of one part of query with form criteria in image below) and added the query as a sub-form

[image]

The problems I have are -

1. When, I run the query itself and input the parameters that are prompted it returns the correct number of expected rows but all fields state "deleted"
2. When I double click on the form, instead of showing the parent form, it shows the sub-form in data sheet format with all rows from database and all have the value "deleted"
3. If I then right click on the presented data sheet sub-forms header and select "Form View", it shows the parent form, but all fields have the value "deleted" and I cannot change them and the subform has no records
4. If I close the form and open again in "Form Design" then right click Form Design and select "Form View", the form view is presented with the first Customer details in database and the sub-form shows the correct number of records for this customer but all fields state "deleted"

can someone tell me how I resolve this please?

Comment: Delete the link to that table. Then relink it, carefully pointing out which field holds the unique or primary key.

Comment: @Gustav do you mean the link from the parent form to the table or the link from sub-form to source object and master\child fields?

Comment: The link to table SupportClaim.

Comment: Make sure no fields with bit type (sql server) are null. Make sure ALL bit type fields have a default of zero. And add a timestamp column to all the tables.

Comment: If that query is subform RecordSource and that criteria references main form, be aware that subform loads before main form, therefore main form reference is not available to subform when form/subform opens. Why would a double-click do anything - is there code in Double-Click event? What is main form RecordSource? I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. Assume this is a split db - what is backend? Edit tags to reflect.

Comment: post is not clear: as I interpret... when the user selects a Customer (single record form, data entry) - there is to be a sub form (continuous style) showing all that customer prior records [limited to 1 year look-back].

if this is so - then the sub form is made standalone and then inserted into the main form.  the customer key is not present in the main form until customer select, then sub form must be requeried.

Comment: @Gustav I apologise for late response but was snowed under here.  I deleted the link to all tables and recreated them all but the outcome is still the same.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal i apologise for late response but very busy with some other things.  I ensured a timestamp column exists in all tables but the outcome is the same

Comment: I have amended the form to use a button that "requeries" the subform through a macro.  the subform uses the query I outlined.  As I said the query run on its own returns the correct number of rows but al fields still states "#Deleted".  I the form when I enter the relevant information in the fields and click the button now nothing happens

Comment: As noted, check for any bit fields that are null (without default of 0). Also add that timestamp column. Note that the timestamp column has ZERO to do with time - it is a row version column that access will use to determine if the record been updated. Without this column, then access can get confused and will display that deleted scenario that you note.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal yes, I scripted the bit fields to have a default of zero if empty and ensure all tables have a timestamp but the outcome is still the same